# Python group dict values on same date

Tags: python, arrays, parsing, dictionary

My question is, how can easily group some dict key, value on same key. Group different values based on key, better explanation I will provide in code.

## dict

```
values = [{
        "date": "2015-05-07",
        "yt": 630.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-07",
        "fb": 16555.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-07",
        "tw": 1234.0
    }]
```

Here is example of my dictionary. What I want to do is check **date** and if that date exists somewhere in dictionary collect values on same date. Output would be like:

```
   values = [
    {
    "date":"2015-05-07",
    "fb":16555.0,
    "tw":1234.0,
    "yt":630
    }
```

The whole dic:

```
values=[
    {
        "date": "2015-04-24",
        "fb": 16322.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-04-24",
        "tw": 1206.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-04-28",
        "tw": 1215.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-04-30",
        "tw": 1224.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-04-30",
        "fb": 16408.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-01",
        "tw": 1226.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-01",
        "fb": 16436.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-02",
        "tw": 1227.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-02",
        "fb": 16451.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-04",
        "fb": 16506.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-04",
        "tw": 1229.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-05",
        "tw": 1232.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-05",
        "fb": 16526.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-06",
        "tw": 1232.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-06",
        "fb": 16541.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-07",
        "yt": 630.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-07",
        "fb": 16555.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-07",
        "tw": 1234.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-08",
        "fb": 16568.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-08",
        "tw": 1238.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-09",
        "fb": 16582.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-09",
        "tw": 1237.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-10",
        "fb": 16594.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-10",
        "tw": 1237.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-11",
        "tw": 1242.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-11",
        "fb": 16600.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-12",
        "tw": 1243.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-12",
        "fb": 16618.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-13",
        "fb": 16630.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-13",
        "yt": 630.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-13",
        "tw": 1246.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-14",
        "yt": 630.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-14",
        "fb": 16635.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-14",
        "tw": 1249.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-15",
        "yt": 630.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-15",
        "fb": 16644.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-15",
        "tw": 1252.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-16",
        "yt": 630.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-16",
        "tw": 1254.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-16",
        "fb": 16654.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-17",
        "tw": 1255.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-17",
        "fb": 16668.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-17",
        "yt": 630.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-18",
        "yt": 632.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-18",
        "tw": 1257.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-18",
        "fb": 16678.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-19",
        "fb": 16688.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-19",
        "yt": 634.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-19",
        "tw": 1256.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-20",
        "yt": 634.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-20",
        "fb": 16695.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-20",
        "tw": 1259.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-21",
        "tw": 126.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-21",
        "yt": 635.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-21",
        "fb": 16698.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-22",
        "tw": 1262.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-22",
        "fb": 16712.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-22",
        "yt": 635.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-23",
        "fb": 16726.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-23",
        "yt": 636.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-23",
        "tw": 1264.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-24",
        "tw": 1265.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-24",
        "yt": 636.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-24",
        "fb": 16731.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-25",
        "yt": 636.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-25",
        "tw": 1269.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-25",
        "fb": 16752.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-26",
        "yt": 637.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-26",
        "fb": 16766.0
    },
    {
        "date": "2015-05-26",
        "tw": 127.0
    }]
```

## code

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for v, k in values: res[k].append(v)

print res
```

Python version: 2.7

Comment: What do you want to do if some value repeats?

Comment: I want to discard it.

Comment: Like two dictionaries with same `date` and same `key` but different value . What do you mean discard?

Comment: Really in this it can not be happend, date is  unique.

Comment: http://ideone.com/BUGpnG

Comment: Thank you for you answer @AnandSKumar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the dictionaries based on the same `date` , for each `date` create a dictionary (that would be used to append to the result list) ,lets call this `maindict`, and then update the `maindict` with the dictionaries from the group. Example -

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
nvalues = []
for dt, k in groupby(sorted(values,key=itemgetter('date')),key=itemgetter('date')):
    maindict = {'date':dt}
    for d in k:
        maindict.update(d)
    nvalues.append(maindict)
```

Please note, this would use the latest value for each `key` in the resultant dictionary, if there are multiple such keys in `values` list for same `date`.

Another thing to note is that [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) expects the list to be sorted according to the key with which to group, hence we have the following in it - `sorted(values,key=itemgetter('date'))` . If the list is already sorted according to the `date` , then that is not needed.

---

Demo -

```
>>> values = [{
...         "date": "2015-05-07",
...         "yt": 630.0
...     },
...     {
...         "date": "2015-05-07",
...         "fb": 16555.0
...     },
...     {
...         "date": "2015-05-07",
...         "tw": 1234.0
...     }]
>>>
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> nvalues = []
>>> for dt, k in groupby(sorted(values,key=itemgetter('date')),key=itemgetter('date')):
...     maindict = {'date':dt}
...     for d in k:
...             maindict.update(d)
...     nvalues.append(maindict)
...
>>> print(nvalues)
[{'date': '2015-05-07', 'tw': 1234.0, 'fb': 16555.0, 'yt': 630.0}]
```

Comment: Thank you for logic @Anand S Kumar

Comment: Glad I could be helpful. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
for x in values:
    if x["date"] in d:
        d[x["date"]].update(x)
    else: 
        d[x["date"]] = x

print d.values()
```